# Inheritance issue with <p> and <ul>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to force CSS to style each `<p>` element inside `<p>` element with a border. It works well till I get to a point where I have a `<ul>` inside my paragraph basically it just stops adding the style.

```
& > p {
   padding-left: 20px;
   border-left: 10px solid $headerGrey;
}
```

Now the only logical conclusion was adding a  marker to this style:

```
& > p,ul {
   padding-left: 20px;
   border-left: 10px solid $headerGrey;
}
```

However I do get the border to my `<ul>`, there is a really nasty gap between `<ul>` and `<p>` elements.

Is there a clean solution for this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me.

```
 & > div {
      display: block;
      padding-left: 20px;
      border-left: 10px solid $headerGrey;
    }
```

So it works like that:

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li> Point with border</li>
  <li> Point with border</li>
  <li> Point with border</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `p` and `ul` elements have default margins. Add this to avoid the gap between them:

```
p, ul {
 margin: 0;
}
```

```css
p,
ul {
  background: #ccc;
}

ul,
p {
  padding: 20px;
}

.no_margin p, .no_margin ul {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>p-tag with default margin</p>
  <ul>
    <li>li tag inside ul tag  with default margin</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="no_margin">
  <p>p-tag with margin: 0</p>
  <ul>
    <li>li tag inside ul tag  with margin: 0</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Problem solved I was using <p> element as an container for <ul> which is an inheritance issue instead of p we've used here  <div> as <ul> holder and it works like a charm.